# Change XSLT of the SearchResultWebPart during the FeatureActivated

Tags: search, sharepoint-2010, xslt, feature-activation

I have a piece of code which changes XSLT of a SearchResultWebPart at Sharepoint 2010 Search Center result page (spFileItem - is SPFile of a search result page) :

```
SPLimitedWebPartManager wpManager = spFileItem.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
foreach (WebPart wpItem in wpManager.WebParts)
{
    if (wpItem is CoreResultsWebPart)
    {
      ((CoreResultsWebPart)wpItem).UseLocationVisualization = false;
      ((CoreResultsWebPart)wpItem).Xsl = someXSL;
      wpManager.SaveChanges(wpItem);
}
spFileItem.Update();
spFileItem.CheckIn(Consts.CheckInComment, SPCheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
```

But, this code doesn't work if it is called on feature activated (gives InvalidOperationException - incorrect object state). However it perfectly works in Console application.
After some reflecting, I found out that there is a piece of code inside the SearchResultWebPart, which checks if the webpart wasn't initialized - it throws the mentioned above exception on setting XSL property. Does anybody know how to work this problem out? For me it'd be quite convenient to do XSL change at FeatureActivated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, but it uses different way of setting xsl for SearchResultBaseWebPart.

```
SPLimitedWebPartManager wpManager = spFileItem.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
foreach (WebPart wpItem in wpManager.WebParts)
{
    if (wpItem is CoreResultsWebPart)
    {
      ((CoreResultsWebPart)wpItem).UseLocationVisualization = false;
      ((CoreResultsWebPart)wpItem).XslLink = spFileItem.Web.Url + @"/_layouts/XSL/MYXSL.xsl";
      wpManager.SaveChanges(wpItem);
    }
}
spFileItem.Update();
spFileItem.CheckIn(Consts.CheckInComment, SPCheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel you mix up a few things in the question. You would like to set the *Xsl* property of the ***CoreResultsWebPart***. This class has no direct implementation of the *Xsl* method, so it inherits the implementation of its parent class (***SearchResultBaseWebPart***). The *Xsl* property setter try to set the *XslHash* property (but only if we are after the OnInit that sets _BeforeOnInit = false;), and the setter method of the *XslHash* property throws an *InvalidOperationException*, but this exception should be catched by the try/catch block in  *Xsl* property setter anyway. I don't see any other potential source of *InvalidOperationException* in the code.

You should check the patch level of your SP2010 (is it SP1/some of the cummulative updates/original version?) and try to activate the feature from different contexts (from web site / STSADM or PowerShell).

But first I suggest you to add a try / catch block to your feature receiver code and [trace out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.traceinformation.aspx) the error details (like [stack trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace.aspx)) and monitor the results using [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647).

Comment: Well, actually it doesn't matter for me which realization it calls :). And as for XslHash - it is a private field and I guess Xsl property - is better way to set web part xsl, as it cares about XslHash by itself... Anyway, you are absolutely right about the _BeforeOnInit, as I mentioned - the webpart class hadn't called OnInit when FeatureActivated is raised and as result I'm not able to set Xsl. STSADM and PowerShell are not an option for me :(, because I want to patch this XSL, when the feature is activated from Web. Thanks for your quick response!